# Lua: Remove a character from string

Tags: lua

How would i for an example remove the h from "helloh" so it will look like "ello"

---

I have no idea what else to write but it looks like i need to write some more text and maybe add some code so this is just junk.

```
print("junk 1")
print("junk 2")
print("junk 4")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used [string.gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) to replace characters, `gsub` stands for **g**lobal **sub**titusion.

```lua
print(("helloh"):gsub("h", "")) -- replace all instances of `h` with empty string
```